# высота grid элементов по высоте контента самого элемента

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Есть верстка элементов на grid. Мне необходимо высоту каждого элемента grid подогнать под размер его контента, но я уже все перепробовал. Т.е. что бы все блоки grid были прижаты друг к другу. У меня это пока не получается сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, как эти можно сделать. Спасибо.

```css
.internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
}

.internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
}

.internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block p:first-child {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #000000;
}

.internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block p:not(:first-child) {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses">
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>А</p>
    <p>Автозаводская, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4/1, 4/3, 4/2, 5</p>
    <p>Агрогородок, ул.: 4а, 7, 18, 19, 20, 32, 100, 101, 102</p>
    <p>Адмирала Горшкова, ул.: 7, 11, 15, 17, 19</p>
    <p>Адмирала Кузнецова, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7</p>
    <p>Адмирала Макарова, ул.: 8</p>
    <p>Адмирала Нахимова, ул.: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17</p>
    <p>Аллейная, ул.: 7</p>
    <p>Андрея Белого, ул.: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Б</p>
    <p>Береговая, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8б, 69</p>
    <p>Брагина, ул.: 1, 3, 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Г</p>
    <p>Героев, просп.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10</p>
    <p>Гидрогородок, ул.: Б, В, А, 3а, 4, 9</p>
    <p>Главная, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7/1, 7, 9, 11/1, 11, 12, 15, 15а, 20, 22/1, 22, 24, 26, 32/23</p>
    <p>Граничная, ул.: 5, 7, 9/1, 9, 10, 10а, 11, 11/1, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36а, 36, 38а, 38, 40, 42</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Д</p>
    <p>Детская, ул.: 9, 11/3, 11/2, 11/1, 11</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Ж</p>
    <p>Железнодорожный, пр-д.: 29</p>
    <p>Жилгородок, ул.: 1, 2, 4к1, 5а, 6, 7а, 9а, 41, 52, 54, 55, 63</p>
    <p>Жуковского, просп.: 1, 2, 3, 4/1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>З</p>
    <p>Заводская, ул.: 4, 6, 10, 12, 14, 18, 29, 33, 39, 41а, 43, 45</p>
    <p>Западная, ул.: 2, 21</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>И</p>
    <p>Интернациональная, ул.: 20, 22, 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>К</p>
    <p>Калинина, ул.: 1, 2а, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24</p>
    <p>Керамическая, ул.: 13, 15, 20, 23/1, 24, 28, 30, 32, 66</p>
    <p>Колхозная, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12/1, 12/2, 12/3</p>
    <p>Комсомольский, пр-д.: 2</p>
    <p>Красный Текстильщик, ул.: 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Л</p>
    <p>Ленина, ул.: 1/5, 2, 4а, 5, 6б, 6, 6а</p>
    <p>Лесные Поляны, ул.: 3, 4, 5, 6, 19</p>
    <p>Лесопарковая, ул.: 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18</p>
    <p>Луговая, ул.: 2, 2/1, 9, 9/2, 12, 14, 16</p>
    <p>Ляхова, ул.: 3, 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>М</p>
    <p>Маяковского, ул.: 1, 2, 4а, 4, 5, 5/1, 5/2, 9/1, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14а, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 36, 42</p>
    <p>Морская, ул.: 1, 2, 3</p>
    <p>Московская, ул.: 1, 3, 5/1, 5/2, 8, 10</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Н</p>
    <p>Некрасова, ул.: 3а, 4, 5, 6а, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 15</p>
    <p>Новая, ул.: 5, 6б, 7, 9, 9а, 11, 13, 15, 18, 18а, 20, 20б, 20а, 22а, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 49</p>
    <p>Носовихинское, ш.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13к1, 13, 15, 21, 22</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>О</p>
    <p>Октябрьская, ул.: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 25/3, 25/1, 25/2, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>П</p>
    <p>Павлино, мкр.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15/1, 16, 17, 18/1, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39а, 39, 67, 69</p>
    <p>Пионерская, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5/1, 5/2, 5, 6, 7а, 7, 8, 9а, 9, 10, 11, 12а, 12, 12б, 14, 14б, 15, 17, 18а, 19/2, 19/1, 19, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 33</p>
    <p>Поликахина, ул.: 1, 3, 5</p>
    <p>Почтовая, ул.: А, 2а, 2/1, 3, 4, 4/1, 5/1, 6а, 7, 8, 10</p>
    <p>Пролетарская, ул.: 1/2к2, 1/2к1, 2/2, 2/1, 2, 3, 4, 5а, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 27, 47, 49, 50</p>
    <p>Пушкина, ул.: 2, 4, 6, 6б, 8, 10, 12</p>
    <p>Пушкинская, ул.: 30, 49</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Р</p>
    <p>Рождественская, ул.: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>С</p>
    <p>Саввинская, ул.: 1/1, 2а, 3, 5а, 9б, 10, 12, 13, 17, 17а, 17б</p>
    <p>Саввинское, ш.: 2, 4/2, 4/1, 4, 6, 10, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 23а</p>
    <p>Свободы, ул.: 1а, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7а, 8/1, 8, 9а</p>
    <p>Смельчак, ул.: 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12</p>
    <p>Советская, ул.: 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 26, 28, 34, 40, 42, 46, 57, 59, 61</p>
    <p>Соловьева, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5/1, 5</p>
    <p>Спасский, бул.: 4, 6</p>
    <p>Струве, ул.: 3/1, 3, 5, 7, 7/1, 9, 9/1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Т</p>
    <p>Транспортная, ул.: 2, 3а, 4, 6, 6а, 19</p>
    <p>Троицкая, ул.: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Ц</p>
    <p>Центральная, ул.: 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 26, 35, 40, 41, 43, 45, 47, 68/1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Ч</p>
    <p>Чаплыгина, ул.: 1, 3, 5, 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Ш</p>
    <p>Шестая, ул.: 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15, 17</p>
    <p>Школьная, ул.: 2, 3/1, 4, 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses_block">
    <p>Ю</p>
    <p>Юбилейная, ул.: 1а, 1, 2/1, 2, 2/2, 3, 4а, 4/3, 4/1, 4/5, 4/4, 4, 5, 6/1, 6, 7а, 7, 8, 8/2, 8/1, 9, 11/3, 11/2, 11/1, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 18/1, 20, 20/1, 22/1, 22</p>
    <p>Южная, ул.: 3, 5, 7</p>
    <p>Южное Кучино, мкр.: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что видно в инспекторе, высота ячейки и так занимает ровно столько, сколько занимает контент. Есть два нюанса: у вас задан `grid-gap`, который добавляет расстояние между ячейками; параграфы имеют стандартный `margin`, что также раздвигает ячейку - добавление стиля `p { margin: 0 }` решает проблему.

Comment: Автор, по всей видимости, хочет, чтоб было как в mansory.js - плитка с элементами разной высоты в зависимости от контента. Но grid-auto-flow: dense не помогает

Comment: тоже сперва про это подумал, но вряд ли masonry-раскладка - это то, что нужно для такого типа контента :)

Comment: Не подскажете, куда добавить p { margin: 0 }. Просто уже во все p пробовал добавлять. Не помогает.

Comment: например `.internet_connectedhouses_content_blocks_symbolhouses p { margin: 0 }`

Comment: и так тоже не помогает (

Comment: Никто не поможет? :(

Comment: давайте спервай сойдемся во мнении, что вот так - это норм https://i.imgur.com/9qwVWhX.png
а то вероятно, что мы говорим про разное

Comment: Для заказчика это не норм ) Уже решил вопрос параметром column-count. Сами блоки - display: inline-grid.